# Masonry extra gutter

Tags: html, css, jquery-masonry

In my page i have 3 panel, column width is 280px and gutter is 10px, right and left panels width are 280px and center panel's width is 560px and because of it, left panel's gutter is 20px.

How can i remove this extra gutter and set it 10px. picture is:

[image]

java script for these panels:

```
var container2 = document.querySelector('#push-below');
    var msnry2 = new Masonry( container2, {
        // options
        columnWidth: 280,
        gutter: 10,
        itemSelector: '.panel'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the column width and gutter width doesn't add up to fill all of the containers width. You could try recalculating the column width to fit, so that the smaller columns consist of several virtual columns. Or for the easy (and ugly) solution, just try to set the columnWidth to 10.